# puppetlabs firewall module support UNTRACKED state

Tags: puppet, firewall

The puppetlabs-firewall module does not support UNTRACKED state, is there any way to do this:

```
firewall { '003 accept related established rules':
  proto  => 'all',
  state  => ['RELATED', 'ESTABLISHED', 'UNTRACKED'],
  action => 'accept',
}
```

*Desired Behavior:*

```
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED,UNTRACKED
```

*Actual Behavior:*

> Error: Parameter state failed on Firewall[003 accept related established rules]: Invalid value "UNTRACKED". Valid values are INVALID, ESTABLISHED, NEW, RELATED.  at /root/fw.pp:3

- Module Version: 1.9.0
- Puppet Version: 4.10.1
- OS Name/Version: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You should raise this in the Jira at tickets.puppet.com in the project MODULES and mention the puppetlabs/firewall module.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. here is the ticket: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-5111